# How to read & parse file using java script?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code I am reading a file Which contains latitude & longitude , I am sotring the file content in an Array .But I don't want to store it  array ,Is there any other options so that  I can store & process it.

I am generating a map with these lat & lon in a for loop,I am passing these to a function,In  an array you can not give a delay so I want other method

Here is My code :

```
  function FileHelper()
    {}
    {
        FileHelper.readStringFromFileAtPath = function(pathOfFileToReadFrom)
        {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", pathOfFileToReadFrom, false);
            request.send(null);
            var returnValue = request.responseText;

            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    var pathOfFileToRead = "LatLon.txt";

    var contentsOfFileAsString = FileHelper.readStringFromFileAtPath
    (
        pathOfFileToRead
    );
    **var contentsArray=new Array();
    var contentsArray = contentsOfFileAsString.split('\n');**  




    function main()
    {
        for(i=0;i<contentsArray.length;i++)
        {
            addMarker();
        //  setTimeout(function() { remveh1();}, 2000);  

        }
    }

    function addMarker()
    {
        console.log(contentsArray[i]);
        split_contentArray=contentsArray[i].split(',');
        vehicle_lat=split_contentArray[0];
        vehicle_lng=split_contentArray[1];


         var vehicle = new MQA.Poi({ lat: **vehicle_lat**, lng: **vehicle_lng** });
         var icon = new MQA.Icon('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gpsmapicons/blue/gpsmapicons07.png', 26, 26);          
         vehicle.setIcon(icon);
         vehicle.setKey("abc");

         map.addShape(vehicle);

        vehicle.setRolloverContent("Vehicle # KA05 9999");

        }




    function remveh1()
    {
        map.removeShape(map.removeShape(map.getByKey("abc"))); 
    };
```

Comment: *"In an array you can not give a delay"* - What do you mean by "delay"? Please describe more clearly what you are trying to do. If you want the markers to appear on the map one at a time with a delay between each one then an array is still the appropriate place to store them all, you just need to change the code that displays them...

Comment: I am trying to display a position on map,based on lat lon ,i dont want to store file  in an array,Is there any other way to store file??

Comment: What's wrong with an array? If you have a whole lot of similar things such as a series of coordinates then an array is the most obvious and best structure to store them in. Again, you mentioned "a delay" in your question but didn't explain what that actually means here. What effect are you trying to achieve? From the user's point of view what would happen if it worked the way you want it to?

Comment: Actually what I want is ,I want a delay b/w displaying position on map ,From the above code I am displaying all the position at one time,I want to display them one by one ,How should i do that

Answer (score 0):

> **Actually what I want is, I want a delay b/w displaying position on map. From the above code I am displaying all the position at one time, I want to display them one by one, how should i do that**

By way of (simplified) background, the browser uses the same thread to run JavaScript as it does to repaint, so if you try to update the page within a `for` loop the entire loop will complete before the actual repaint. You would deal with this by replacing the `for` with an algorithm based on `setTimeout()` calls. In between timeouts JS is "inactive" (not intended as a technical term) so the browser can repaint.

Your code includes calls to functions that you don't show, so I can only suggest a fairly minimal update to it, changing `addMarker()` to accept a reference to a marker as an argument rather than relying on global `contentsArray()` and `i` variables, and then rewriting `main()` to pass the appropriate marker object when it calls `addMarker()`:

```
function main() {
    var i = -1;
    (function processNext() {
       if (++i < contentsArray.length) { // if there are markers left
          addMarker(contentsArray[i]);   // add the next one
          setTimeout(function() {        // then delay before
            remveh1();                   // removing it and then
            processNext();               // process the next one
          }, 2000);
       }
    })();
}

function addMarker(marker)
{
    console.log(marker);
    split_contentArray = marker.split(',');

    // rest of your function here unchanged
}
```

(Simplified) demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3ao3wved/